# Angular 4 router-outlet content

Tags: angular

I need to display the same block on every router-outlet link. Its just a header but the title and some buttons are managed from app component.

I basically need to do something like this:

```
<router-outlet>
   <md-toolbar (click)="someAction()"> {{ title }} </md-toolbar>
</router-outlet>
```

And inside of every router-link something like this:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
<h1>This is my page</h1>
<p>blablabla</p>
```

So the md-toolbar tag would be inside of the page

Answer (score 0):

`<router-outlet>` is not supposed to have any content. It's just an anchor where the router adds components.

You can use an empty-path route with a dummy component (show-nothing-component) to display your default content before the user navigates to the detail view.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it like this:

```
<md-toolbar (click)="someAction()"> {{ title }} </md-toolbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Then it will appear at the top above the routed content.

If you need to have some components without the toolbar and some with, you'll need another intermediary component.

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Route to the above router outlet if you need *no* menu or toolbar.

**shell.component.html**

```
<md-toolbar (click)="someAction()"> {{ title }} </md-toolbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Route to the above router outlet for any content that does need the toolbar.

**Route Configuration**

```
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
            path: '',
            component: ShellComponent,
            children: [
                { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
                { path: 'x', component: XComponent},
                { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
            ]
        },
        { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },   // <-- no toolbar
        { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent } // <-- no toolbar
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks, I alredy did that but I forgot to tell that I need to display the toolbar just in some cases, and those cases are mostly related with the pages content.

Comment: Then you'll need to do what Gunter suggested. I updated my answer to include an example of what he mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do it in this way? Can't you just type it like that:

```
<md-toolbar (click)="someAction()"> {{ title }} </md-toolbar>    
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This toolbar would be generate everytime above your router-outlet. You don't have to use `<ng-content>`

Comment: Thanks, I alredy did that but I forgot to tell that I need to display the toolbar just in some cases, and those cases are mostly related with the pages content